# Multiple listeners / go blocks for channel in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

Given a channel in ClojureScript

```
(def navigation (chan))
```

Is it possible to have multiple go blocks that pull values off it? E.g.

```
(go
 (while true
   (secretary/dispatch! (<! navigation))))

(go
 (while true
   (println (<! navigation))))
```

The putting a value in with:

```
(put! channels/navigation "/styles")
```

This doesn't seem to work and only executes within the first Go block. This is a bit of a contrived example but I do want to use this pattern to have multiple listeners to a channel that will return JSON from a socket.io service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from a channel will return the value and remove it from the channel. If you want multiple readers to read the same values you need multiple channels; take look at the core.async mult and tap functions.

Comment: Thanks @Joost. I realised this about 10 minutes after I created the ticket and voted to close as a duplicate of another ticket I found. Thanks for answering though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [pub](https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/pub) and [sub](https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/sub) functions in `core.async`. This still means multiple channels as @Joost mentioned.